# Wrong Redirection in Laravel 5 built in User Authentication

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I am trying to use Laravel 5 User Authentication.  In this regard my URL is  `http://localhost/lara_project/public/auth/login`  before login. I would like to redirect user to `http://localhost/lara_project/public/home`  after successful login. But it is redirect to `http://localhost/lara_project/public/`.  I tried with routes like below

```
Route::get('home',['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'WelcomeController@index']);

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

Route::controllers(['auth' => 'Auth\AuthController','password' => 'Auth\PasswordController']);
```

which are resided in **routes.php**

My Problem is afrer successful login user redirected to  `http://localhost/lara_project/public/` and if I would like to browse  `http://localhost/lara_project/public/home` after successfull login it is showing error

```
This webpage has a redirect loop
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

I tried by editing **RedirectIfAuthenticated.php**,**compiled.php** and **AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers** files. But could not get any satisfactory result.

Could anyone help me in this regard ??

Answer (score 2):

Go to Auth\AuthController and add a variable $redirectTo = 'home';

This with tell laravel where to redirect to after login.

Comment: Thanks @Carthagian Traveler for your reply. Your solution is not working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Modify `RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` as below

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->auth->check() && !$request->is('/home'))
    {
        return redirect('/home');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Please also have a look at here. I am using some kind of code as below.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!$request->is('authenticate') && !$request->is('authenticate/login') && !Auth::check()) {

        return $request->ajax() ? response(array("status"=>'404')) : redirect('authenticate/login');
    }
    if(Auth::check()) {
        if( ! $request->user()->isAdmin() ) {
            return $request->ajax() ? response(array("status"=>'404')) : redirect('authenticate/login');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Pratik Soni. Your solution is not working. Thanks

Comment: can you try `!$request->is('home')` and let me know?

Comment: I tried `!$request->is('home')`. Now the error `This webpage has a redirect loop
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` is not coming, I can see the `home` page. But after successful logged in it is redirecting to   `http://localhost/lara_project/public/`. I need redirection to `http://localhost/lara_project/public/home`.

Comment: I have edited the code. Please see the code and let me know

Comment: Thanks @Pratik Soni. Your solution is not working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Go to /app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php

There you can change `protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;` that to what you want.